# What is the best time/stage to ask Hosts/listers for phone verification?

Tags: verification

For holiday rental apps such as Airbnb, booking.com and likes. What is the best time/stage to ask Hosts/listers for phone verification? On signup or after they list the property? Keep in mind, they have to verify before the property is published!

Answer (score 0):

I would force it on listing and soft-suggest on registering, that way, verification isn't a blocker to registration and there's value in the user going through the process on listing to secure a service.

Answer (score 0):

> The earlier, the better but not too early that you lose the game even
>   before it starts.

Phone verification makes sure that:

1. The user and his/her contact info is authentic
2. The user is genuinely interested in utilising the services
3. People can reach out to the user appropriately when needed

The trick is to ask the user for verification when he/she shows interest towards utilising the services but without annoying them, which could lead to user bounce back.